# Statment concerning open sets and closures

Tags: general-topology

I found the following line in a proof (from a good book) concerning locally compact spaces:

> Since $A$ and $B$ are both open and $A \cap B = \varnothing$, it follows that $\bar{A} \cap B = \varnothing$.

Probably quite blindly, I really don't see why it is the case.

*Is there somebody who can enlighten me?*

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $B$ is open, $X\setminus B$ is closed. And $A\subset X\setminus B$ by assumption. Therefore $\overline{A}\subset X\setminus B$.

Comment: Why does it follow that the closure of a proper subset (of a closed set) is itself a proper subset?

Comment: @muaddib The inclusions need not be proper, $\subset$ is the same as $\subseteq$. For proper inclusions, I use $\subsetneq$ or $\subsetneqq$.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong (because I got a sudden enlightment): The point is that since $\bar{A}$ is the intersection of all closed sets $Y$ s.t. $Y \supset A$, then it has to be the case since $A \subset X \setminus B$, that $\bar{A} \subset X \setminus B$.

Comment: @Kolmin Better than "the intersection of all ..." is the characterisation "the smallest closed set containing $A$", I think. But yes, that is the point, we know a closed set containing $A$ and not intersecting $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in order that $x \in \overline{A}$ it must be the case that $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$ for every (open) neighborhood $U$ of $x$. (This is, in fact, an equivalence.)

If $B$ is open and $B \cap A = \emptyset$, then $B$ is an open neighborhood of each of its elements witnessing that they are not in $\overline{A}$.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can follow this trace:

> If $x \in \overline{A} \cap B$, noticing that $B$ is open, then $B$  as the neighbourhood of $x$, $B \cap A=\emptyset$, a contradiction!

Comment: Is there a mispelling or a missing word?